# How to create file upload form in Bigcommerce checkout page and link it to order ID?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, handlebars.js, bigcommerce, bigcommerce-checkout-sdk

I have gone through Bigcommerce documentation and also the tutorial videos on their official Youtube channel, there they taught about editing theme files, however my requirement is to let the users upload a file, save its path into BigCommerce database and access the file path and display it with order ID on Orders page after users have checked out.
I don't find their documentation on connecting to and accessing database.
Is there a place where articles on interacting with Bigcommerce database are available?

Answer (score 0):

BigCommerce doesn't provide any native database access, but you can use BigCommerce API to access data if you needed to do so. Per reading your question, I believe you may be able to use [webdav](https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/File-Access-WebDAV) to upload your file and [link it to specific pages](https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/How-do-I-add-and-link-to-a-file-in-my-store), if that's more of what you're looking to do.

--Update--

We do currently have an idea in the community for this to be supported natively. You can comment and vote for it to show support and to raise the awareness to our engineering teams. [Find it here](https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/ideas#0874O000000LdDyQAK)!

I know this isn't a solution for right now, but your support would help this idea become natively supported. We do have the ability to upload files on the product level, [like this](https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Product-Options-v3#file-upload).

Comment: I want to let users upload a file, save the file into a folder and access the file once users have returned from payment gateway after payment and associate the file with order id and save it somewhere, probably in a DB and show that file for download in Orders page of store owner.

Comment: I've added an update to the above answer.